# Angular 2 , value returned before function complete

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, observable

In my Angular I have a service that draws a picture on a canvas ang get its "ImageData".

This is my service.ts:

```
getColorArray (movie: MovieDb): Observable<any> {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w342/" + movie.poster;
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = 50;
    canvas.width = 30;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return of(imgData)
  }
```

And my .ts where I use it:

```
pixelate(movie) {
    this.getBackgroundColor.getColorArray(movie)
    .subscribe(r => do something with r)
```

I've made it as an Observable thinking that `imgData` would be returned when `getImageData()` is done but it's returned as soon as `getColorArray()` is called.
How can I wait for `getImageData()` to complete before returning its value?

Comment: `getImageData()` is not an asynchronous API. My guess is that you have another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem isn't "waiting for `getImageData`", it's waiting for the image to load, and you need to do that explicitly. something like:

```
getColorArray (movie: MovieDb): Observable<any> {
  // create an observable
  return new Observable(obs => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w342/" + movie.poster;
    
    // once the image loads, draw it and the image data is available synchronously
    var imgLoadListener = e => {
      var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = 50;
      canvas.width = 30;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      obs.next(imgData);
      obs.complete();
    };

    img.addEventListener('load', imgLoadListener);
    
    return () => { // clean up after yourself.
      img.removeEventListener('load', imgLoadListener)
    }
  })
}
```

a way to this a bit cleaner / less manually is like so, using `defer` and `fromEvent`, which will handle some of the cleanup work for you and handle errors a bit better:

```
getColorArray (movie: MovieDb): Observable<any> {
  // defer to not create image until subscribe
  return defer(() => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w342/" + movie.poster;
    
    return fromEvent(img, 'load').pipe(
      map(() => {
        var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = 50;
        canvas.width = 30;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        return imgData;
      })
    ); 
  })
}
```

you COULD remove the `defer` part above and it'd work just fine, but it's standard practice in observables to make sure they do nothing until subscribed to, which the use of `defer` accomplishes here.

Comment: Works perfect, now I have to figure out that `fromEvent()` so I can use it in the future :)

Comment: just creates observables out of DOM element events

Comment: But my `img` is not in the DOM, or is it?

Comment: it's not attached to your current document, but it's still a DOM element. `new Image()` is just a prettier shorthand for `document.createElement('img')`